# classic "ValueError: Truth value of a series is ambiguous"

Tags: python, pandas

This is a watered down version of my situation. I am working in a code environment I cannot modify. On the back end, there is a function that resembles `add_sigma`. I am needing to assign the function to execute across rows where the "value" column holds a particular string. The function itself forces me into a boolean expression. Any way around this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def add_sigma(percent):

    if percent >= 99.9997:
        return 6
    elif percent <= 99.9996 and percent >= 99.98:
        return 5
    elif percent <= 99.979 and percent >= 99.4:
        return 4
    elif percent <= 99.39 and percent >= 93.3:
        return 3
    elif percent <= 93.29 and percent >= 69.1:
        return 2
    elif percent <= 69.09 and percent >= 30.9:
        return 1
    elif percent <= 30.89 and percent >= 0:
        return 0


df = pd.DataFrame({'value': ['0-3 bucket', '4-7 bucket', '8+ bucket', '0-3 bucket', '0-3 bucket', '8+ bucket'],
                   'percentage': [27.68, 82.94, 32.26, 91.97, 99.82, 67.44]})

df['sigma'] = ''
df['sigma'] = np.where(df['value'] == '0-3 bucket', add_sigma(df['percentage']), df['sigma'])
```

expected output would be

```
        value  percentage sigma
0  0-3 bucket       27.68     0
1  4-7 bucket       82.94      
2   8+ bucket       32.26      
3  0-3 bucket       91.97     2
4  0-3 bucket       99.82     4
5   8+ bucket       67.44
```

Comment: What's wrong with being forced into a boolean expression though? `np.where` seems like it'd work well here.

Comment: Note that the main issue with your code is not the boolean expression, but the way `add_sigma` is being called. Try replacing `add_sigma(df['percentage'])` with `df['percentage'].map(add_sigma)` or use the `loc` option I suggested in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/51319645#51319645).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like cs95 said, you can use conditions and call the add_sigma function. One way to do it is to include the condition inside the apply like this:

```
df['sigma'] = df.apply(lambda x: add_sigma(x.percentage) if x['value'] == '0-3 bucket' else '',axis=1)
```

The result will be:

```
        value  percentage sigma
0  0-3 bucket       27.68     0
1  4-7 bucket       82.94      
2   8+ bucket       32.26      
3  0-3 bucket       91.97     2
4  0-3 bucket       99.82     4
5   8+ bucket       67.44
```

Using .loc, you can do :

```
df.loc[df['value'] == '0-3 bucket' , 'sigma'] = df['percentage'].map(add_sigma)
df['sigma'] = df['sigma'].fillna('')
```